# ionic installation and build difficulties

Tags: ionic-framework

Creating a new ionic project and doing an android build downloads innumerable packages; if anything goes wrong in this process, many things can get corrupted. I am now on my fourth re-install of Windows, for example.

Is there a way of downloading everything required for an ionic install and android build first so that I have all the downloads safely in place before I start on installation? This would also give the benefit of being able to create a number of projects without having to download everything again.

Comment: what's going wrong in build process?

Comment: Usually a huge slew of errors. I presume that if a download of some component fails, then the whole thing gets thrown off. 

Also I am unable to combine eg camera and audio in the same app without interminable problems.

Answer (score 0):

What I do now make copies of folders and base new projects on folders that are correctly downloaded and functional. Even a simple ionic project downloads and creates a folder of approx 200 MB. I find that this process can often go wrong.

On a good day, I can run

```
ionic start <projectName> blank
```

and answer YES to the question "Would you like to integrate with Cordova"

This then generates a folder of about 200 MB. If I am unlucky something goes wrong and this fails.

I check that the folder is correct by running

```
ionic serve
```

and verifying that the browser shows a basic page.

I then run

```
ionic cordova build android --debug
```

This increases the folder size to around 270 MB. Finally, I confirm that I can FTP the *.apk file to a website and install it to an android device.

I then make a copy of this folder and use that copy as a basis for all new projects. I never run "ionic start" again.

I have never had problems with the installation of other development environments, so this seems very unusual. I can only assume that the complexity of the installation can lead to faults. Achieving one correct download and then copying that is how I handle these problems. The best time for me in Scotland is to do installations in the middle of the USA night.